# Can't change default output folder

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

all

I can't change the default output folder in Eclipse.

When I open "Properties" -> "Java Build Path" -> "Source", the default output folder is

```
<project_name>/bin/classes
```

I changed it to

```
<project_name>/bin
```

save and clean-build this project. It changed back to

```
<project_name>/bin/classes
```

This happened after I updated my ADT plugin to 15.0.1

Some configurations:

```
Eclipse:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers<br/>
Version: Indigo Service Release 1<br/>
Build id: 20110916-0149

ADT Version: 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398

OS: Mac 10.7.2

SCM: Git 1.7.4.4
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Johnny

Comment: I have the same problems. Looks like some kind of bug/limitation of ADT. As soon as I build the project, it changes the output folder setting.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, except that I'm trying to change my directory to war/WEB-INF/classes but it won't let me. And (I think because it wont' let me) I'm getting classdefnotfound errors.

Answer (score 6):

From [Android Changes in Revision 14](http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14):

> Change to the bin output folder. While the Ant build system puts the
>   output of javac in bin/classes/, the configuration of the Android
>   projects in Eclipse uses bin/, like standard Java projects. This has
>   always been a small problem because we put other files in there (like
>   the apk and dex files), but also need to use this folder as the source
>   of the dex step. Thankfully, dex would just ignore those files. Since
>   we started putting resource items in there too (png crunch cache), we
>   decided to change the project output (as far as the JDT is concerned)
>   to bin/classes/. ADT still uses bin/ as its top-level output folder
>   for Android specific files. The visible side effect is that bin/ will
>   now show up in the Package Explorer view (but not bin/classes/ as JDT
>   hides the only output folder it knows about).

This seems to imply that Android has it's own build settings and replaces the JDT build settings (i.e. "output folder" under Properties->Java Build Path->Sources) to match.

The blog ["A Little Madness"](http://www.alittlemadness.com/2010/05/31/setting-up-an-android-project-build/) describes how to change the out.dir property of ADT's Ant by adding/changing the file build.properties in your project's root folder.  You can also change the location of gen.dir with build.properties.

```
out.dir=bin
gen.dir=gen
```

Note that Eclipse has had problems in the past with external tools modifying classes in its output folder, and its possible that out.dir=bin/classes for this reason.

Disclaimer:  I haven't tried any of this, yet.  This suggestion may fix nothing, cause different problems, or, hopefully, work.

Comment: This is the correct answer; building Android apps is NOT the same as building Java projects, and the structure of the output is decidedly different.

Comment: just to note that changing the output folders doesn't work when dealing with library projects - there's part of the Ant script that is hardcoded to look in the bin folder of libs anyway.