# Change default output bin folder of Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Eclipse puts binaries in "project folder/bin/" by default. I'd like to have Eclipse put generated binaries etc in another folder (outside the project folder). Doing Android development.

Comment: why do you want to do like this?

Comment: It makes project folder cleaner and easier to share, copy and so on. Especially using Dropbox and using several workstations for the same projects. This is default setting in Xcode, which I guess at one point was based on Eclipse.

Comment: Hmm can't find any backup sources for that so I guess Xcode is not based on Eclipse at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the "output folder" (by default bin) for a Java project (see "[How do I change a Java project's bin folder in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191693/how-do-i-change-a-java-projects-bin-folder-in-eclipse)")

But for Android projects, as detailed in "[Can't change default output folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321853/cant-change-default-output-folder)", you need to modify the `build.properties` as well.
That can be dangerous though, [as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321853/cant-change-default-output-folder#comment17552679_8865084):

> Just to note that changing the output folders doesn't work when dealing with library projects - there's part of the Ant script that is hardcoded to look in the bin folder of libs anyway.

So maybe using the [exclude option](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/Using_Dropbox_CLI#EXCLUDE) of Dropbox is preferable here?

Comment: Ok, I'm checking this right - there seems to be no other easy way. Maybe I should try something else than Eclipse some day...

Answer (score 2):

I would like to describe an approach below.

First, create a **new empty project** locally in eclipse work space for storing generated output files say output_bin.

As mentioned in above steps, now from **Default Output Folder** we need a new Variable to link to our project output folder.

1. Default Output Folder -> Browse -> **Create New Folder...**
2. -> Advance -> check "Link to folder in the file system" ->
3. **Variables** -> New.. -> Name = PROJECT_OUT, Location = "**CHOOSE_PATH_TO\output_bin\bin\Project1bin**" -> Ok

*Note*: Project1bin is a new directory which stores the bin folder. output_bin is an empty project and you can have multiple bin folder for various projects.